# How to use a module in a different file

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to use a module located in the same folder (cgi-bin) in another file

I have something like this

```
package ModuleName;
sub …
```

and in the other file I have

```
use ModuleName;
```

is there a special way to import not library files, or files in the cgi-bin along side perl scripts?

Everything worked when they were both in the same file.

Both files have the appropriate head `#!…`

Comment: Although it doesn't hurt anything (it's just weird), modules don't need a `#!` line. That's only needed in files which will be run as programs so that the shell (on *nix systems) will know which interpreter to use to execute the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the module exports your sub (with `Exporter` and `@EXPORT_OK` (or `@EXPORT`, but that's less polite)), you'll need to refer to it as `ModuleName::my_sub` instead of just `my_sub` in the code that uses the module.

**Edit:** Seeing the error message in your comment on the earlier answer, your first problem is that modules must return a true value when loaded.  This is conventionally accomplished by adding the line:

```
1;
```

as the final line of the module file.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could add:

```
use lib '/path/to/directory';
```

which will allow you to set an additional directory for loading modules from.  Make sure your module file name ends in a .pm too.

Comment: I've tried both relative and absolute paths, neither worked :-(
I tried with and without the #!path to perl at the top of the module and the module is does end in *.pm.  Is there anything else I could be doing wrong? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Well, definitely use absolute not relative paths.  do you have errors in your web server's error_log file?  That'd be the place to look.  It could be an selinux issue to if you have selinux turned on.  The files will need to have the right selinux context.

Comment: This is the error I am getting

[Thu Mar 31 05:53:47 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportFile.pm did not return a true value at C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/Assign-3/survey.pl line 13.
[Thu Mar 31 05:53:47 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/Assign-3/survey.pl line 13.
[Thu Mar 31 05:57:40 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: survey.pl

Comment: You possibly just need a "1;" at the end of the ImportFile.pm file. The last statement in a "use"d or "require"d file has to produce a "true" value.

Comment: Relative paths work, too. Apache will set the working directory to the directory where the CGI program resides, so `use lib '.';` will generally work for cases like this.

Comment: Your a genious :-), that worked, but do all modules require a one at the end, and out of curiousity why? and Thank you to everyone that helped.

Comment: @rubixibuc: Yes, all modules must return a true value. `1;` is just the standard way of doing this. The reason is so that perl has a way of knowing whether a module was loaded successfully - if it returns a true value, it succeeded; if it returns a false value, it failed.